# Recursive queries in Elasticsearch/Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have hierarchical Elasticsearch data, which I "normalized" into documents of the following mapping:

```
_id | custom_id | parent_id | text | value
```

Where `_id` is the autogenerated Elasticsearch id, `custom_id` is an unique integer I assign and `parent_id` acts as a foreign key, referencing `custom_id` of a document when the the current document is a child of the referenced one. An example of two documents could like this:

```
abc | 1 | -1 | foo | 123
def | 2 | 1 | bar | 456
```

Every document has exactly one (any `parent_id` > 0) or no (`parent_id` = -1) parent. The nesting can become arbitrarily deep, but is always bounded  and there will most likely be multiple top level parents.

My goal is to query the data for two answers:

- Given a `custom_id`, what are all parents (so direct parent, grandparent, ...) of this document?
- Given any query result, apply a filter that only childs of a given `custom_id` (which itself needn't be part of the original query result) match.

Elasticsearch `join` datatype is not applicable, because in my case, a single document can act as parent and child at the same time. The `nested` datatype does not allow this kind of searching.

To be clear, I want to return the query results in Kibana. Writing a script that does return one document at at time, recursively walking through the `parent_id` is certainly possible. What is required of me to make this work in Kibana and present the results either in the Discover page or in a visualisation (I think data table is a good fit)?

Answer (score 0):

This is something you need to address in a different manner when working with document based databases (elastic, mongo etc). There is no connect by prior or recursion in elasticsearch...

But there is a good documentation for the most common solutions for this problem in mongo db documentation but they are easily adaptable for elasticsearch. All of them have up and downsides. In my past, solutions based on 'nested set' or 'materialized path' worked very well for linked- or tree based structures.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/

Have Fun!